# Estrutura CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2

Estou iniciando um projeto em CakePHP 2.X e ele possui CMS + Website.

Gostaria de saber a **melhor forma (correta e usual)** de estruturar os arquivos, pois não gostaria de manter todos os arquivos juntos, isto é, os arquivos do Back e do Front num mesmo Model, Controller e/ou View.

Se a melhor forma (ou única) seja juntando, tudo bem. Mas gostaria de saber se tenho outras opçoes de estruturar os arquivos para uma melhor organização do projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de uma pesquisa em alguns fóruns a melhor opção, no meu caso, foi desenvolver a aplicação como se fosse um Plugin do Cake.

Muitos programadores utilizam desta técnica.